# I am trying to install debian. which download to select?

Tags: windows-8, debian, intel-core-i7, architecture

I am trying to install debian on local computer with Windows 8 OS and intel core i7 processor.

On the download page. I was asked to select my processor architecture with the following options listed

amd64
armel
kfreebsd-i386
kfreebsd-amd64
i386
ia64
mips
mipsel
powerpc
sparc

If so, which do I select for my debian installation?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the version that you select depends on what architecture your processor is (x86 or x64). Generally nowadays, everything is x64 based as it allows for more RAM ([>4GB, usually less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869563/how-much-memory-can-be-accessed-by-a-32-bit-machine)). You say that you're running Windows 8 - and if that's 64-bit then your processor will be too. This is just to check, as it's quite likely it's 64 bit anyway. Head to the control panel and find "system" (you can search "system", and hit the first result.) There, if you're running a 64-bit version of Windows 8, "x64-based PC" is displayed in the " system type" field under the "item" heading.

So, go for the **amd64** installation. The others are for other, differing architectures of processor - and most consumer chips are of this architecture today.

Answer (score 0):

You should select a net install with amd64 (for 64 bits processor)